# Cordova-plugin-firebase: Cannot run on iOS 12.2 but works without any problems on android and iOS 10.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

Hej Guys

I have a cordova app with cordova-plugin-firebase version: 2.0.5. The plugin is working fine on android and on iOS 10.3.3. The notifications are received without any problems both from firebase and our notification server.

The problem is with iOS 12. On iOS 12.2 the app starts up fine, runs the grantpersmission code and the user is prompted with grant permission dialogue but when trying to acquire token as following:

```
window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function (token) { backend_registration(token); console.log(token); }, function (error) { console.error(error); });
```

the getToken/onTokenRefresh callback is never called and the app crashes. If I comment the code out for registering the app for notifications/firebase the app doesnt crash.

Cordova-cli: 7.1.0
Cordova-ios: 4.5.5

Hope somebody can point me to a solution.

I have also created a issue on the plugins github page where I also attached xcode log [here](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1041).

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly I changed the build system to Legacy in File -> Project Settings.
2. Secondly, I used an Authentication APN Key (not Certificate as mentioned in the Medium guide, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs).
3. add to config.xml

   ```
   <platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIBackgroundModes">
     <array>
       <string>remote-notification</string>
     </array>
    </config-file>
   </platform>
   ```

This fixed it for me.